# SDL2 event callback without polling

Tags: c++, event-handling, sdl-2

Is it possible to use an SDL_[EventWatch](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AddEventWatch?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryEvents%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29)/[Filter](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetEventFilter) without polling for new events?

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

 int SDLCALL watch(void *userdata, SDL_Event* event) {
        std::cout << event->type << "\n";
    return 1; // or 0
}

int main( ){
    SDL_Window *window {SDL_CreateWindow("Window", 100, 100, 400, 400, 0)};
    SDL_Renderer* renderer {SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED)};

    SDL_SetEventFilter(watch, NULL);

    function.Call("main"); // non-C++ function with endless loop

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

There is already an endless loop in `"main"` which controls most of the application. I would then call an appropriate Lua-function depending on the SDL_Event given to `watch(..)`.

This code does not react on any event.

Comment: Hi, can you show us your non-C++ main function? I think you still need to poll or maybe open or make SDL open a thread which might handle your events. If you are running a loop you have to somehow give SDL the chance to handle the events. Also check this wiki entry: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetEventFilter

Comment: I think this would not help you much. The main function does a lot of logic, which you can script very fast in languages like Lua or Python. It also does some SDL-rendering C-calls of course. Your comment seems to lead to a negative answer to my question. I've kind of expected that. :)

Comment: That would be problemmatic to do in a portable way. Why is that a problem? You have to have renderer flush point anyway, why is event queue considered differently?

Comment: Why do you imply that I see this as a problem? This is not a problem, it's just a way to do it different. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dr. Gerhard Stein stated in the comments:

> If you are running a loop you have to somehow give SDL the chance to handle the events.

So the answer is simply *no*.

Comment: I find this answer confusing. The comment states you need to allow SDL to handle events which is true, but your last sentence makes it sound like you disagree. I think this deserves more elaboration.

Comment: I disagreed with regarding my attempt to try something 'different'  as a problem.